# C#: Android phone control

Tags: c#, android, interface, usb

Would it be possible to control/interface with an Android phone through USB in a WinForm application? Is there any library for that, without using any original Android tool (ADB, fastboot)?

Comment: Why do you want to talk to the phone over USB?  Why not use a web service or some such standard protocol?

Comment: What do you think "control (interface with)" means? What do you think "standardized application" means?

Comment: What do you think "USB" means? What do you think "stinkbug" means?

Comment: My goal is to create a C# frontend (or call it a PC Suite) for Android phones. "Standardized application" is my fault, I thought about some library what is developed to do what I want (so control the phone many ways, ask for things like installed apps, contacts, messages, etc, and also control like ADB). "Control" "Interface with" are two separate terms, "Control/ interface with" would be the good expression.

Comment: Hello fonix232, had you found that lib?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [Managed Android Debug Bridge](http://madb.codeplex.com/).

It's in C# and says:

> This is a Managed port of the Android Debug Bridge to allow communication from .NET applications to Android devices. This wraps the same methods that the ddms uses to directly communicate with ADB. This gives more flexibility to the developer then launching an adb process and executing one of its build in commands.

Answer (score 1):

The only USB support in Android is for `adb` and USB mass storage. Neither let you talk to on-device applications. Both let you access files on the SD card. `adb` may provide additional features, but you cannot  access "installed apps, contacts, messages". None of this is designed to work from C#, though you can call out to the `adb` command-line executable if you wish.

A network-based protocol would be easiest, for a subset of your goals. A Bluetooth protocol may be doable for the same subset.

Comment: I saw a few applications written in C# what could do this, but unfortunately they weren't opensource or weren't complete. As an example, Android Manager (what is deceased and only has a preview, the beta executable got lost).

Comment: Basically what I want is an ADB port in C#. So to communicate with the phone, ask for specified data, and so on. But looks like noone made such a thing yet.

Comment: Well the source for adb is hidden somewhere in here, I looked for a while but couldn't find it right away. http://android.git.kernel.org/ for a port. Also, its still open source so you could just include adb.exe in your application package and make system calls to it to do your bidding.  The user won't need the android SDK installed just the drivers

Comment: Yes I could make the call, but still a C# binding/total port would be very nice and a lot more useful, as there would be no need for executables, just one, the WinForm app itself. Also, I have the source, but it is pretty complicated :S

Comment: @fonix232: "Basically what I want is an ADB port in C#." -- `adb` does not let you access "installed apps, contacts, messages".

Comment: In a tricky way, it does ;)
It lets you access the so called Terminal - where you can do anything. Call a list of installed applications - easy, just listing files in a given directory/directories, and gathering some data about it. Messages/Contacts - all stored in specific files. Just cat them and got them all. What do you think those Message/Contact/Application managers are built upon?

Comment: @fonix232: You cannot use `adb shell` to access anything of what you have described here on a regular production device. You most certainly cannot "do anything". This would be trivial for you to test with your own non-rooted Android phone.